# Passing Javascript array value to Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I want to pass/store JavaScript array[totalData] variable to Laravel controller. And How to insert multiple rows to database? Please help me.

[Js functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6hxd.png)

Comment: do it via ajax call? no? there is no way you can set JS value to PHP variables on client side.  Have a redirect and pass the parameters in the url

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to encode the array in the front end and then decoding it in the backend.

You can achieve this by:

Front end:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(totalData));

// some xmlHttpRequest (eg: axios)
axios.post('/yoururl', formData, headers).then(() => {}).catch(() => {});
```

Then in the backend,

```
public method somefunction(Request $request)
{
    $request->request-set('data', json_decode($request->data));

    // validation and other stuff

    foreach ($request->data as $data)
    {
        /Insert to database
    }
}
```